# Попадают ли точки в указанную область

Tags: c#

[image: Парабола]

Задача: определить по введенным пользователем N координатам (xi, yi)
попадают ли они в указанную закрашенную область. Вывести на экран ответ в виде последовательности сообщений (Yes/No)

Comment: Ну постарайтесь сначала словами описать, какие условиям должны удовлетворять точки, потом записать это математически, и затем перевести на шарп

Comment: Тяжело разобраться с условием, изобразить параболу и по ней смотреть не трудно, тяжело разобраться что находится выше оси Ox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вверху область ограничена прямыми y=x (при x>=0) и y=-x (при x<0). Это можно определить одним неравенством

```
y <= abs(x)
```

Ну и объединить это условие по AND (`&&`) с неравенством для параболы